# Installation problem

Tags: ce-1.9.1.0, installation

I am trying to install this and and am getting this error - could you please let me know what the problem is.

```
Error in file: "C:\Program Files (x86)\Ampps\www\magento1\app\code\core\Mage\Sales\sql\sales_setup\upgrade-1.6.0.8-1.6.0.9.php" - SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'magento.sales_flat_quote' doesn't exist, query was: DESCRIBE `sales_flat_quote`
```

Trace:

```
#0 C:\Program Files (x86)\Ampps\www\magento1\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Resource\Setup.php(644): Mage::exception('Mage_Core', 'Error in file: ...')
#1 C:\Program Files (x86)\Ampps\www\magento1\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Resource\Setup.php(437): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup->_modifyResourceDb('upgrade', '1.6.0.8', '1.6.0.9')
#2 C:\Program Files (x86)\Ampps\www\magento1\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Resource\Setup.php(320): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup->_upgradeResourceDb('1.6.0.8', '1.6.0.9')
#3 C:\Program Files (x86)\Ampps\www\magento1\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Resource\Setup.php(235): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup->applyUpdates()
#4 C:\Program Files (x86)\Ampps\www\magento1\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\App.php(428): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup::applyAllUpdates()
#5 C:\Program Files (x86)\Ampps\www\magento1\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\App.php(354): Mage_Core_Model_App->_initModules()
#6 C:\Program Files (x86)\Ampps\www\magento1\app\Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#7 C:\Program Files (x86)\Ampps\www\magento1\index.php(83): Mage::run('', 'store')
#8 {main}
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems some DB issue as it's looking for table `sales_flat_quote` but can't found. That is because you have some incomplete installation data exist in the database.

Start the fresh installation again.

[Magento 1.x Installation with sample data](http://www.extendtree.com/magento-introduction/magento1-x-installation.html)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Please take a fresh magento setup and start fresh installation, please make sure you have make below changes in XAMPP php.ini file:

```
max_execution_time = 5000
max_input_time = 5000
memory_limit = 1000M
```